# Check if slider have been moved

Tags: matlab, slider, matlab-guide

How do I check if a slider in a MATLAB GUI have been used, i.e. the user have interacted with the slider?

The slider is given by the following GUI code:

```
uicontrol(fig,'Style','Slider','Units','characters','Position',[17.1+f*iwidth 10.5 8 59.6],'Min',0,'Max',1000,'Value',500,'SliderStep', [1/500 , 20/500 ],'Tag',['slider' int2str(f)]);
```

Is there a clever way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you need to add is a callback function. You can add it with the same uicontrol command.

```
uicontrol(fig,'Style','Slider','Units','characters','Position',[17.1+f*iwidth 10.5 8 59.6],'Min',0,'Max',1000,'Value',500,'SliderStep', [1/500 , 20/500 ],'Tag',['slider' int2str(f)], 'Callback', @myfunc);
```

then you need to write the myfunc, something like this:

```
function myfunc(source,event)
value = source.Value % This is the position of the slider
end
```